# SPServices will not load

Tags: jquery, sharepoint, spservices

**In the heading of my page, I have:**

```
<script>
function insureSPServices(callbackFunction)
{
  if($().SPServices == null)
  {
     jQuery.getScript("./scripts/jquery.SPServices-2014.01.js", callbackFunction);
  } else {
      callbackFunction.call(null, "Already Loaded");
  }
}
function populate()
{
alert("SPServices loaded? " + (jQuery.SPServices == undefined ? "NO!!!" : "YES."));
}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
  $(document).ready(function()
  {
    alert("jQuery");
    alert("!" + $().SPServices.SPGetCurrentSite() + "!");
alert("jQuery loaded? " + (jQuery == undefined ? "NO!!!" : "YES."));
alert("SPServices loaded? " + (jQuery.SPServices == undefined ? "NO!!!" : "YES."
));
    insureSPServices(populate());
  });
</script>
```

**I get:** 
JQuery YES
SPServices NO!!!
SPServices NO!!!

**Notes:**
The two script paths are legitimate.

The SPServices script was downloaded from:
  http://spservices.codeplex.com/downloads/get/786994

The check/init logic is from here:
  http://devspoint.wordpress.com/2011/01/07/quick-way-to-load-spservices/

All help appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There might be several problems:

1. The path may not be resolved correctly (sometimes relative urls seem just not to work correctly in SharePoint context)
2. When using jQuery in Javascript within e.g. a SharePoint webpart try to use jQuery.noConflict() before using the SP-Services. In most cases I had issues with using $ or jQuery because of the already loaded JQuery within SharePoint.
3. When using javascript in SharePoint $(document).ready might cause problems because this doesn´t actually mean that all content is loaded. You can try to use _spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("myfunction") instead.

Answer (score 2):

I also stuck with this problem for couple of hours. For me the answer was to use jQuery.noConflict() in jQuery declaration. Like this:

```
<script src="../../myLib/jquery-1.11.3.min.js" type="text/javascript">
jQuery.noConflict();
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

When using jQuery within SharePoint Web Part try to use [jQuery.noConflict()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/). In many cases there are issues using `$` or `jQuery` because of the already loaded jQuery within SharePoint.